# Taxation on Annual Incentive Plan bonus after relocation to a different US state

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, bonus, relocation

Each year, Bob, a US tax resident, receives some money in February from his employer in the US as his [Annual Incentive Plan](https://www.decusoft.com/annual-incentive-compensation-a-complete-guide/#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20an%20Annual%20Incentive,company%27s%20short%2Dterm%20performance%20goals.) bonus. During the year 2022, Bob relocated from California to Washington state. When Bob files his US taxes in April 2023, does he owes any tax to California resulting from his Annual Incentive Plan bonus?

Comment: when did he move? The money was received in February, but where did he live/work when the money was received?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Moved in March 2022. Money is received yearly in February. I wonder if the money received in Feb 2023 will be taxed by California.

Comment: The money is payed out while Bob is a tax resident of WA - they owe no CA tax on it. Bonuses are not guaranteed, and are taxable (perhaps) when payed out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Bob will owe taxes to California. Bob relocated in March 2022, and the money was paid in February 2022, when Bob was a CA tax resident, as such it is taxable in CA.

For February 2023, the money will have been received when Bob is no longer a CA tax resident, and will not be taxed in CA. This of course assuming the CA FTB accepts Bob's position that Bob terminated the residency.

Bonuses are treated as salary and are taxable when paid.

See examples [here](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/misc/1100.html) (especially the "compensation" part).

Comment: Does CA pro-rate tax owed if you are a resident for part of the year - e.g. if you are a resident for one month you owe 1/12 of the tax you would have owed if you were a resident for the whole year?

Comment: @DStanley for bonuses? No. For SOs and RSUs - yes.